# How to customize GIDSignInButton login Image in new Google+ iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8, google-plus

In order to connect to google plus in my iOS app i'm using GIDSignInButton from  [latest Google Plus SDK for iOS.](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/)

I want to use my own image and label for login button. The problem is I don't see anywhere how to customize it. I am able to do it in previous SDK versions.

Any solutions????

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It's not possible to customize the sign in button the same way it was in the older SDKs. The older SDKs contained an image you could replace. The new SDK does not.

Having said that, you do not have to use a `GIDSignInButton` to sign in the user. If you want to use a custom image, just use a custom `UIButton` and call `[[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn]` on touch.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thanks

Comment: using [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn] on UIButton, i encounter "Custom Scheme URIs are not allowed for 'WEB' client type", using the CLIENT provide in configuration plist.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks @Steve.

Using the same custom `UIButton` in `Swift` 4 :

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```